# Using While Loop In A Simple SysTray PyQt5 Application

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have this very simple systray application:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from datetime import datetime

class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        self.setToolTip(f'Tray Test')
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent)
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Exit")
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exit)
        self.setContextMenu(menu)
        diag = QtWidgets.QColorDialog()

    def exit(self):
        self.hide()
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.exit()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("1.png"), w)
    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I wanted to add a never ending while loop that prints the current time every second like this:

```
while 1:
    datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Whatever I tried, it froze the systray.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QTimer class provides repetitive and single-shot timers.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from datetime import datetime
import time

class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        self.setToolTip(f'Tray Test')
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent)
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Exit")
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exit)
        self.setContextMenu(menu)
        diag = QtWidgets.QColorDialog()

    def exit(self):
        print("exit")
        self.hide()
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.exit()



def read_data_from_sensor(label_data):
    dt  = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    label_data.setText(dt)
    label_data.adjustSize()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.show()
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("im.png"), w)
    trayIcon.show()

    label_data = QtWidgets.QLabel(w, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    label_data.setGeometry(160, 80,  200, 50)
    label_data.show()

    timer = QtCore.QTimer(w)
    timer.setInterval(1000)                             
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda l=label_data: read_data_from_sensor(l))
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]